# Iterating through an array of objects in jQuery and matching attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I'm trying to loop and group through this object array using jQuery using my loop value.

[image: my jsonObj]

I'd like the final object to look like this.

> [
>       {'organization':'ABC Inc', 'address':'123 Front', 'city':'Wilmington','state':'NC','zip':'09900'},
>       {'organization':'Wonton Inc', 'address':'555 Front', 'city':'Jasper','state':'NC','zip':'09877'},
>       {'organization':'ABC Inc', 'address':'123 Front', 'city':'Wilmington','state':'NC','zip':'45345'}
>   ]

Comment: Post the original object and the loop script you used to console log each attributes. Maybe there is not much missing to group them.

Comment: please do not post images of code....

Comment: I meant to simplify since the code is very complicated. @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `hash table` and [***`#reduce()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to extract the data structure required - see demo below:

```js
var object = [{loop:0, key: 'organization', value:'ABC Inc'}, {loop:0,key:'address',value:'123 Front'}, {loop:0, key: 'city',value:'Wilmington'},{loop:0, key:'state',value:'NC'},{loop:0, key:'zip',value:'09900'}, {loop:1,key:'organization',value:'Wonton Inc'},{ loop:1, key:'address',value:'555 Front'}, {loop:1,key:'city',value:'Jasper'},{loop:1, key:'state',value:'NC'},{loop:1, key:'zip',value:'09877'}, {loop:1, key:'organization',value:'ABC Inc'},{loop:1, key:'address',value:'123 Front'},{loop:1, key:'city',value:'Wilmington'},{loop:1, key:'state',value:'NC'},{loop:1, key:'zip',value:'45345'}];

var result = object.reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c) {
    if(!hash[c.loop]) {
      hash[c.loop] = {}
      p.push(hash[c.loop]);
    }
    hash[c.loop][c.key] = c.value;
    return p;
  }
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks it worked exactly they way I wanted it to